# PHP array not setting correctly in try catch statement

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, try-catch

I am using an array to log key information in a foreach statement for use later on, I set the array at the top of the page to ensure that it is available across all functions in the script.

I have tested to see that the array is set, and it seems to work outside a try catch statement see commented code below.

```
$completeClients = array();

if($can_synchronise === true)
    {
            $success = sync_to_client($package, $client);
            try 
            {
                if($success)
                {
                    $completeClients[] = "Sync to ".$client->getName()." has completed";
                }
                else
                {
                  $completeClients[] = "Sync to ".$client->getName()." has failed";
                }            
            }
            catch(Exception $ex) 
            {
                logMsg("Unable to save client data reason: ". $ex->getMessage(), STATUS_ERROR , $client->getAddress());
            }
            exit( EXIT_OK );//Exit the child process
        }           
    }
    else
     {
        **// The array is set correctly when called here**
        $completeClients[] = "Sync to ".$client->getName()." has failed";
    }
```

I have printed the array and when it is called in the try catch statement it looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Sync to TPSDEV_PHILIPS_TWO has completed
)
Array
(
    [0] => Sync to TPSDEV_TC_Client2 has completed
)
Array
(
)
```

It should look like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Sync to TPSDEV_PHILIPS_TWO has completed
)
Array
(
    [0] => Sync to TPSDEV_PHILIPS_TWO has completed
    [1] => Sync to TPSDEV_TC_Client2 has completed
)
Array
(
    [0] => Sync to TPSDEV_PHILIPS_TWO has completed
    [1] => Sync to TPSDEV_TC_Client2 has completed
)
```

Do you guys have any idea? im stumped.

Comment: It seems you have an extra brace `}` after `exit( EXIT_OK );`

Comment: @hallaji: No, that's the closing `}` for the `if` statement on the first line. OP is using the Allman coding style (sort of crossed over with Whitesmiths style)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't add up:

```
exit( EXIT_OK );
```

It's outside of the try-catch block, so whatever happens (succesful or otherwise), after inserting the first value in the array, you're exiting the script. As soon as the branch `if ($can_synchronise  === true)` gets executed once.
What's more, there's no loop to be seen anywhere, so how do you expect this to produce an array that contains more than 1 value?

There's something else, too: you're calling the `sync_to_client` *outside* of the try-catch block, which only contains an `if-else` and an assignment to an array. Nothing that might throw an exception AFAIK, unless `$client->getName()` throws, but the name implies a getter, which is unlikely to throw in the first place.
You probably want to call the `sync_to_client` in the try-catch, if that's the function that is likely to throw an exception.

Lastly, if this *is* part of a loop of some sort, and you've posted just the inner code, then you really ought to move this:

```
$completeClients = array();
```

out of the loop, because now, each time this block of code gets executed, you're reassigning `$completeClients` to hold a new, empty array.
Assuming an array of client objects, your code should look something like this:

```
$completeClients = array();
foreach($clients as $client)
{
    if (!$canSynchronize)
    {
        $completeClients[] = 'Sync to '.$client->getName().' has failed';
        continue;//messy, best wrap the try-catch in an else branch
    }
    try
    {
        if (sync_to_client($package, $client))
        {
            $completeClients[] = 'Sync to '.$client->getName().' has completed';
        }
        else
        {
            $completeClients[] = 'Sync to '.$client->getName().' has failed';
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        logMsg("Unable to save client data reason: ". $ex->getMessage(), STATUS_ERROR , $client->getAddress());
        //$completeClients[] = 'Unable to Sync: '.$e->getMessage();
        //exit( EXIT_OK);
        throw $e;//rethrow, is what I'd do.
    }
}
```

However, what this code effectively does is catch exceptions, and sort-of hush them up. If something fails, there's likely to be a bug in your code. Don't catch an exception unless you know how to deal with it. And don't catch *everything*.
`PDO` throws `PDOException` instances. SOAP clients throw `SoapFault`'s, my objects throw either `InvalidArgumentException`, `RuntimeException` or `BadMethodCallException` instances. There are many types, each one of them signals a specific type of problem. Don't try to be [yoda, playing pokemon](http://www.dodgycoder.net/2011/11/yoda-conditions-pokemon-exception.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if mentioned code placed inside an array or function, however I think if you replace following with something else it can help

```
$completeClients = array();
```

with

```
if (!isset($completeClients)) {
    $completeClients = array();
}
```